# VBA to delete active slides in powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete slides in Active Powerpoint Presentation but I have an error on  **sld_id = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex**

```
Sub DEL()
  Dim i As Long
  Dim sld_id As Long
  sld_id = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex
  With ActivePresentation.Slides
    For i = .Count To sld_id Step -1
      .Item(i).Delete
    Next i
  End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with that?
Many thanks!
Roxana

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please search stackoverflow before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below uses Late Binding to PowerPoint (so you don't need to add reference to the PowerPoint library), and it checks if the PowerPoint instance is open.

After, it sets the `ActivePresentation` to `ppPres`.

At last, you loop backwards to delete all the slides from the end until the second slide (only the first slide will remain).

**Note**: You can modify the `For i = ppPres.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1` loop quite easily to fit your needs.

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub DEL()

Dim ppProgram As Object
Dim ppPres As Object
Dim ppSlide As Object
Dim i As Long

On Error Resume Next
Set ppProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

' check if PowerPoint instance is open >> if not raise an error
If ppProgram Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint is closed!"
    Exit Sub
Else
    ' set the ppPres object to active PowerPoint presentation
    Set ppPres = ppProgram.ActivePresentation

    ' always loop backwards when deleting objects (in this case slides)
    For i = ppPres.Slides.Count To 2 Step -1
        Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(i)
        ppSlide.Delete            
    Next i
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ++ nice one... `ppPres.Slides(i).Delete` will shorten it even further :D

Comment: @SiddharthRout true, I guess it's automatic thay I define and set every object. (BTW, love your self made Month-View Calendar)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The VBA codes in the other posts did not worked for me. I had an error on line Set Pre = ActivePresentation on those as well.

Comment: If I want to delete specific slides I will need to use Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(3) - for slide number 3 for e.g. But what if I want to delete more slides? E.g. Slides 3 to 10? Many thanks in advance for your answer! And of course, I will not need the for statement. Am I right?

Comment: @RoxanaVlad modify the `For` loop to `For i = 10 To 3 Step -1`

Comment: @ShaiRado Thanks a lot! That worked like a charm!